# Как сохранить jpg в embedded базу данных

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Нужно сохранять изображение в базе данных. Картинки здоровые с фотоаппарата 15-20 МегаПикселей. Сжимать их нельзя, на фотках есть много мелких деталей, которые просто при сжатии схлопнутся. Хранить предполагается либо SQLite, либо CompactSQL.
С хранением возникает проблема из-за ограничения поля binary. 
Внутри теплиться большая надежда сохранить простоту и удобство простого запроса к базе и прописанного binding-а полей.

З.Ы.Ж. Вариант с сохранением в базу только uri не предлагать.

З.З.Ы.Ж. В голову приходили мысли завести максимально возможное по размеру полу binary и сохранять в него изображения кусочками, кусочками его считывая. Но как-то останавливает, возможные тормоза при разрастании базы данных.

Comment: А почему не воспользоваться методами сжатия, без потери информации?

Comment: Вы что-то путаете. В SQLite нету существенных ограничений, чтобы в него не влез jpeg на пару мегабайт.

Comment: Ограничение было для SqlCompact в гр#@$ 4Кб. Спасибо. Получается вопрос закрыт, и компактный sql покидает студию. А мне остается как всегда рвать волосы за невнимательность.